# Django authentication to Cloud SQL postgresql through GCP IAM

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, amazon-iam

I am setting up a Django project on GCP and I just created a Cloud SQL instance with IAM authentication. I have CloudSQL proxy set up to allow me to connect from my local machine. Unfortunately, when it comes to setting up the Django backend connection, there's only third-party packages for AWS IAM.

Has anyone here managed to connect to a CloudSQL instance with GCP IAM?

Comment: hope you have gone through this https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

Comment: @JyothishBhaskaran I've seen that guide but it doesn't help as it uses a user/password authentication approach, not IAM.

Comment: I am not aware of a package but you can use the Python connector: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/HEAD/tests/system/test_pg8000_iam_auth.py

Comment: However, instead of creating a new Django package using the Python connector, I would install and set up the Cloud SQL Auth proxy and let it handle IAM auth.

Comment: @JohnHanley to be honest, I am all in for letting Cloud SQL Auth deal with the IAM auth, however, as far as I know, I still need to provide the Django backend with some user/password to connect to the database. Maybe I'm missing something (I'm relatively new to Django), but is there a way to let django.db.backends.postgresql authenticate with the database without a password?